# How can I make a field optional in Yup based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, yup

I am using [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) for form validation. I have two fields: 'authorizedService.serviceGround' and 'airService.navFee'/'airService.ofFee.' I want to make them optional. For example, if the user selects 'authorizedService.serviceGround,' then I want to make 'airService' optional, and vice versa. I have tried to resolve this issue but haven't succeeded. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me resolve this problem.

```js
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    clientDetails: yup.object().shape({
        tripNumber: yup.string().required("Trip Number is required"),
        registery: yup.string().required("Registry is required"),
        customerAccountNumber: yup.string().required("Customer Account Number is required")
    }),

    serviceProviders: yup.object().shape({
        companyName: yup.string().required("Company Name is required"),
        email: yup.string().email().required("Email is required"),
    }),

    legAndServiceDate: yup.object().shape({
        serviceDate: yup.date().nullable().typeError('Service Date is required'),
        serviceLocation: yup.string().required('Service Location is required'),
    }),
    authorizedService: yup
        .mixed()
        .when(['airService.navFee', 'airService.ofFee'], {
            is: (navFee: boolean, ofFee: boolean) => navFee || ofFee ? true : false,
            then: yup.object().nullable(true).default(null),
            otherwise: yup
                .array()
                .of(yup.string())
                .nullable()
                .required("Ground Service is required when neither navFee nor ofFee is selected"),
        }),

    airService: yup.object().shape({
        navFee: yup.boolean().required("TBS is required"),
        ofFee: yup.boolean().required("TBS is required"),
    }),

    authorizedCharge: yup.object().shape({
        // total_Charged: yup.string().required("Total Charged is required"),
        // currency: yup.string().required("Currency is required"),
        // totalIsUnknown: yup.boolean().required("Total is required"),
    }),
});
```